# Como funciona um CAPTCHA?

Tags: captcha

Eu entendo que um CAPTCHA é uma forma de eu garantir que o usuário que interage com o meu sistema é um ser humano e não um script.

Porém essa é a explicação simples que a gente dá para pessoas leigas. Como os CAPTCHA funcionam realmente, e que estratégias eles usam? Seria possível ter um exemplo simples de código para demonstrar o conceito?

Comment: meio amplinha:) mas é muito boa.

Comment: Para quem estiver interessado: [Inside recaptcha: Reverse-engineering the new “captchaless”](https://github.com/neuroradiology/InsideReCaptcha).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

CAPTCHA quer dizer *Completely Automated Public Turing test to tell Computers and Humans Apart*, ou seja testes públicos completamente automatizados para diferenciar computadores de humanos.

Em geral, CAPTCHAS são feitos de modo que sejam fáceis de serem resolvidos por um ser humano e difíceis para os computadores. O programa que exibe o captcha normalmente já sabe a resposta correta e apenas confirma se o que o usuário respondeu está correto. Existem diversos tipos de CAPTCHAS

- **Texto**: geralmente algumas letras aleatórias e algum ruído é adicionado (como retas, ou pontos). São apresentados ao usuário na forma de uma imagem.
- **Audio**: geralmente são usados em conjunto com capcthas de texto e exercem função principalmente de acessibilidade para usuários com deficiência visual. São sons com alguns ruidos incluidos.
- **Imagens**: mais recentes. São apresentadas algumas imagens para o usuário e o programa pede para que ele seleciona aquelas de alguma categoria.

Qualquer um pode criar um captcha: desde que seja um teste completamente automatizado.

Aqui vai um gerador feito em R:

```
library(magick)
library(magrittr)
gerar_captcha <- function(base_img){

  letras <- sample(letters, 6, replace = TRUE) %>%
    paste0(collapse = "")

  cap <- base_img %>%
    image_annotate(
      letras, 
      size = sample(30:70, 1),
      degrees = sample(1:60, 1),
      color = sample(c("green", "blue", "red"), 1),
      location = paste0("+", sample(20:100, 1), "+", sample(20:100, 1))
    )

  list(
    letras = letras,
    cap = cap
  )
}
```

Esse código gera captchas desse tipo, com posição, inclinação e cor aleatórias.
Além de letras aleatórias.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No entanto, captchas de texto estão fadados ao fracasso. Não é necessário tanto trabalho para quebra-los atualmente, principalmente usando técnicas de aprendizado de máquina. Eu tenho um projeto de quebrar captchas de serviços públicos (que não oferecem API) e com redes neurais convolucionais estamos atingindo mais de 99% de acerto em diversos tipos de captchas: https://github.com/decryptr/decryptr

Por isso, recentemente as empresas estão desenvolvendo diversas outras formas de verificar se o usuário é humano. A solução mais utilizada hoje em dia é o reCaptcha do Google, que por incrível que pareça, pede apenas que você clique em um botão. Esse capctha analisa diversas informações de sua navegação e da forma com que você clica no botão para dizer se você é humano ou computador, e é bem mais difícil de quebrar do que o capctha por textos.

Uma história interessante sobre captchas foi o seu uso para a criação de bancos de dados de imagens corretamente rotuladas e para transcrição de livros. As primeiras versões do reCaptcha eram da seguinte forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Uma palavra escaneada de um livro (que o próprio fornecedor do captcha não sabia a resposta) e uma palavra gerada (que o programa sabia resposta) eram apresentadas. Com a resposta dos usuários, o programa conseguia identificar e transcrever palavras escritas em livros que haviam sido digitalizados. Algumas versões mais modernas também ajudam o Google a identificar números de casas em imagens do Street View:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então, quando você está respondendo captchas, você pode estar [ajudando o google a melhorar o Google Maps](https://research.googleblog.com/2017/05/updating-google-maps-with-deep-learning.html).

Comment: Uma nota quanto ao Google utilizar o reCaptcha para melhor seu Maps, ela está inovando ainda mais na ferramenta, agora, a maioria das vezes é pedido para escolher pedaços de imagens que contem uma chave principal, por exemplo, carros, ou placas. Uma segunda forma ainda, é uma ferramenta de edição de imagens que funciona para contornar uma parte da imagem que é pedido. Realmente me pegou de surpresa essa segunda.