# Ajuda para traduzir captcha utlizando a linguagem python, csv e tesseract [closed]

Tags: python, csv, opencv, captcha, tesseract

Estou tentando fazer o reconhecimento dessas imagens, tentei de vários tipos e não consigo identificar com o tesserat por causa das linhas e riscos

Pego as informações do site a baixo e não consigo traduzir utilizando o cv2 e o tesseract
Utilizei o código a baixo para teste, mas sem exito

caso preciso de mais exemplos, eu pego neste site
https://afi.santanderfinanciamentos.com.br/scripts/afi_santanderLojista.dll?OPERA=AFI_Home

Captchas utilizados

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

--Codigo que eu utilizei--

```
img = cv2.imread('Imagens/solvCaptch.png')
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
suave = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (3, 3), 0)
(T, bin) = cv2.threshold(suave, 160, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
resultado = np.vstack([np.hstack([bin])])
str = ocr.image_to_string(resultado, lang='por')
print(str)
```

Comment: Favor ler [Como funcionam Captchas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/219553/75104), captchas de textos simples podem ser "quebrados", mas exige Inteligência Artificial ou outras técnicas. Se tornando um pouco mais complexo do que utilizar somente um OCR e uma operação morfológica na imagem.

Comment: Poderia me ajudar com o que eu utilizo ?